# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'. Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Tags: python, tensorflow

I' trying to use TF 1.14 (also tried 1.5, 1.8). But I always get an error

```
Models init error! Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doc\Desktop\JOB\First project\venviroment\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "C:\Users\Doc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Doc\Desktop\JOB\First project\venviroment\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Doc\Desktop\JOB\First project\venviroment\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Doc\Desktop\JOB\First project\venviroment\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

How can I solve this? I use windows 7, python 3.7. Processor - Intel core i3

Please, help!

Comment: How did you install `tensorflow` ? It seems it misses some elements created with C/C++. Maybe it needed to compile some code and you didn't have needed C/C++ compiler. Did you get error during installation ?

Comment: @furas I install it, using my requirements.txt file. On the other PC I did't got any error, but I got this one on my laptop. Installation was successfull, but I've got an error, when I run my django server.

Comment: if you don't get error when you install `TensorFlow` then I don't have idea why you have problem. Use Google to find `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'` - maybe someone already had similar problem.

Comment: Using Google I found this: [Tensorflow 1.6.0 cpu fails on import on Windows 10 #17386](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386). It says you may have this problem if CPU doesn't have instructions AVX and you have to use `1.4` which doesn't use `AVX`. OR you may have to manually compile `TensorFlow` on your CPU. You can also check on [tensorflow-community-wheels](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues) if someone compiled for your CPU, Windows 7, Python 3.7 32bit. I had to compile `1.14` for my Linux Mint and CPU i5 which doesn't have instructions AVX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I installed these under the Linux Mint, there were no problems with TF.